# Deploy .NET within an application

Tags: .net, mfc

Why is there no possibility to deploy the .net-libraries needed for an application within the application? In the MFC there was the ability to deploy the MFC in a static library or so.

Is there a specific reason why microsoft didn't allow this for .net?

Comment: No you can't, you must install the framework, .NET change the way OS works deeply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with deployment in particular during static linking if the dll is updated application will not get the updated version until a update is pushed by the developer.

see deployment issues in pre .net scenario [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293574.aspx)

and how .net resolve them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973843.aspx)